# From square norm to norm in an inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, square-numbers

If I have an inequality involving the norm squared of kind:
$$||\text{something}||^2<||\phi||^2$$ then can I say that then $$||\text{something}||<a_1||\phi||$$ with $0<a_1<1$?

Comment: Well... No. In fact, the second inequality implies that $\lVert \text{something}\rVert^2<a_1^2\lVert \phi\rVert^2$, therefore any bound of that kind you may be looking for, you must already see between the squared quantities.

Comment: But $a_1^2||\phi||^2<||\phi||^2$, not?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: And so it is not possible to say the following? $$||something||<a_1||\phi||\iff ||something||^2<a_1^2||\phi||^2<||\phi||^2$$ if $0<a_1<1$

Comment: For $0<a_1<1$ it is true that $$\lVert \text{something}\rVert<a_1\lVert \phi\rVert\Leftrightarrow \lVert \text{something}\rVert^2<a_1^2\lVert \phi\rVert^2<\lVert \phi\rVert^2$$ regardless of anything.

Comment: @Gae.S. ok thanks so the implication of my question is true?

Comment: No, it is not.${}$

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand...if it holds the "$\iff$", how is possible that the implication is not true?

Comment: You asked if the following is true $$\lVert \text{something}\rVert^2<\lVert \phi\rVert^2\Rightarrow \exists a_1\in(0,1), \lVert \text{something}\rVert<a_1\lVert \phi\rVert$$
By all means, that is false.

Comment: mm..what is the difference with $$||something||<a_1||\phi||\iff ||something||^2<a_1^2||\phi||^2$$ for $a_1\in(0,1)$?

Comment: I can't explain to you the difference between two expressions involving the undefined symbol $\phi$, the word "something" and possibly an insufficient number of quantifiers. What I can do is stating the answer to what I think is your question and provide some generic nonsense that you may adapt to your problem (or not, what do I care?). You want a straight answer? Then ask a straight question (to someone else, because personally I'm done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're saying is right. This is because the first inequality implies that $$||s||<||\phi||$$
Therefore, $a_1=\dfrac{1+\dfrac{||s||}{||\phi||}}2$ will do the desired job.